# Pointer to a 'constprop' function in C

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, function-pointers

I'm currently developing a C code for a RISC-V SoC that I'm compiling using GCC. I have a `foo(a,b)` function, and I need to provide its address to the hardware through a customed CSR (Control and Status Register) using *CSRRW*. As of now, I was defining a macro, compiling/linking the program, changing the value of the macro according to the generated firmware, compiling/linking again and checking that the address didn't change. Nevertheless, I'd like to have a more generic approach, hence the use of pointers.

I tried to simply associate the function base address to a variable (`addr = foo`), which is working most of the time. However, after compiling and linking the code with GCC (and -O3 optimization), I've noticed that 2 versions of the function were created:

- `<foo>`
- `<foo.constprop.0>`

The pointer I get in the code is referring to the first one, however, I would also need a variable to point to the second one. Is there a generic way to deal with this?

#### EDIT:

As [Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) suggested, I created a function `foo_const()` calling `foo(0,0)`. What happens is that GCC is creating `<foo_const>` with a jump instruction only. So a pointer to `foo_const` would not fix the issue.

I also tried to copy and adapt the content of `foo(a,b)` in `foo_const()` by replacing the arguments with constants. This work as the called function is directly the one I created and not the 'constprop' anymore. However, it doesn't really reply to my question as it is a workaround not to point to 'constprop' instead of a way to point to it, and also there is a negative impact on performances.

Comment: First of all, *why* do you need a pointer to the "constprop" function? What are the reasons you need it? Do you even know what this "constprop" symbol really is, and how it differs from the "normal" symbol? What kind of research have you made about GCC and "constprop" symbols? And what is your original and underlying problem you need to solve with a pointer to the function?

Comment: The `foo.constprop.0` is an example of *function cloning*.  The compiler notices that the function could be optimized much better if a certain one of its arguments were a certain constant (e.g. `foo(0)`), and so it compiles a separate version of the function with that assumption.  If another function makes a call to `foo(0)`, the compiler emits a call to `foo.constprop.0()`.  If it calls it as `foo(non_constant_expression)`, the compiler emits a call to the regular `foo`.

Comment: This optimization is supposed to be transparent.  So if you do `void (*my_ptr)(int) = foo;` you will get a pointer to the true general `foo` function which will do the right thing under all circumstances, albeit maybe not as fast as otherwise.  You do not have to, and should not, refer to `foo.constprop.0` in your code at all.

Comment: If you are planning to always call `my_ptr(0)` and want to benefit from the cloned version, the most portable approach is to write a trivial helper function: `void foo_zero(void) { foo(0); }` and then `void (*my_other_ptr)(void) = foo_zero;`.  Then `foo_zero` will be compiled into a call to `foo.constprop.0`, or maybe the constant-propagated version of the function will be inlined directly into `foo_zero`.

Comment: I need to write a CSR with the address of this function, so that the hardware can recognize it. The way I'm doing it now, is to define a macro with a random value, compile and link the code, change the macro with the correct value, compile and link again and check if the value didn't change. I wanted to have a more convenient way to do so, hence the use of pointers. The [simple constant propagation](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html) is basically optimizing instructions which are using only constant operands. That's why I detailed the optimization method I was using.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're describing.  Maybe you can give a more complete explanation in the question?

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge for the detailed explanation. Your solution might work, I'm not sure the generated code will be as efficient though, but I'm gonna give it a try.
I updated the the question to provide more details.